# Any visualization library which does not require user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I am making a visalization which would show how busy a person is. So i have data in the form of name, emailid, busyness_factor, received_date. This is got in an interval of 10 mins.

I tried visualizing it with [cubism.js](http://square.github.io/cubism/) but it still needs user interaction such as hovering the mouse on the generated graph to see the busyness value.

So my question is that is there any visualization library that will not require user interaction? This is because the visualization will be displayed in a giant monitor and users passing by should see and understand the visualization so they cannot get a mouse to hover.

Please suggest any library that currently supports this type of visualization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 big players in this space are **raphael.js** and **d3.js**.

*D3 for obvious reasons:*

1. based on current web standards (html5, javascript)
2. good documentation
3. powerful,robust and reusable
4. jquery style selection

The only place where raphael defeats d3 is fallback; raphael supports older versions of IE whereas d3 is based on current web standards.

I wouldn't even think about library other than d3 if my app is data driven. It is perfectly compatible with *json data* and most importantly works seamlessly with/without user interaction the way we want it to. D3 makes me wonder what 100 lines of code can do.

EXAMPLES:

- [1000 examples and demos](http://techslides.com/over-1000-d3-js-examples-and-demos/)
- [Dynamic Charts Showcase](http://bl.ocks.org/mlarocca/4340039)
- [Dynamically populated charts](http://bl.ocks.org/mlarocca/4339162)
- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4183330

No user interaction required.

Comment: After a lot of reasearch i had zeroed down to cubism.js which is a D3 plugin but that also needs user's interaction. Is there any type of chart that comes to your mind that may suit the purpose ?

Comment: what are you doing in your app??elaborate...so that i can give you an example accordingly

Comment: i have multiple users with a busyness factor(1-10, 10 being most busy) at 10 mins interval. So for example what i did in cubism (the link provided above) was that each user had a row and the busyness factor is rendered pixelwise in the entire row by matching the date.

Comment: so you data is changing every 10 min??and you want to represent them??

Comment: yes data is pushed in every 10 mins for each user. Cubism was good but requires user interaction :(

Comment: accept the answer if you think its worthy!!!

Comment: the first might suit the purpose but how does the world tour chart qualify ?

Comment: thats my personel favourite!!!but the fact that no interactivity is needed for all these is important..any ways..you wont get  the exact thing you are looking for...unless you create it yourself!!!